# Use dispatch 0.9.5 in a Play 2.0 project

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a Play 2.0 project (to be upgraded to 2.1 in the coming months, but not right now). It appears that Play automatically imports the previous version of dispatch (0.8.8). There are important features in dispatch 0.9.5 that I want to use. So I added this to my Build.scala:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    //Some other dependencies,
    "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.9.5"
)
```

However, I don't have access to this version of dispatch in my code. How can I do this?